# Send a WebRequest GET with request body in C#

Tags: c#, get, webrequest

Im trying to request data using GET. I've tried it on Postman, and it already gives expected responses. 
[image]
The problem is I cant implement it on C# code because it has request body.

My current code:

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            //request.Headers.Add("statresp","1");

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.  
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Display the content.  
                Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            }

            // Close the response.  
            response.Close();
```

Server will gives different response depends on the value of request body. However my current code always gets response as if it was sent without a request body. How to do it without having to switch into POST?

Answer (score 0):

- look at the network tab on browser
- inspect element F12(the request and response headers).
- add some header to request like cookies or something.

what is the purpose of this get?